# google spreedsheets & URI.js

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, uri.js

I'm traying to use http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/ to get a url form a cell in my google spreedsheet without the query part.

original url http://test.com/file.php?this=1&that=2  --> from this url i like to get http://test.com/file.php

following this site http://googleappscripting.com/working-with-urls/ i added the example code in my spreedsheet and i can get to functions to work like:

```
    function urlPath(url){
  return URI(url).path()
   }
```

to get the url as i need, i created another function following :the documents here http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/

```
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://rawgit.com/medialize/URI.js/gh-pages/src/URI.js').getContentText());     

function url_whitout(url){
      return URI(url).search("")
       }
```

but i get an error : TypeError: undefined is not a valid argument for URI

Any ideas how i can get this to work?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not a URI.js issue, it is a Google Apps Script issue. You need to get the url into the function first.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var url = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).getValue();
```

The getRange() function has several different versions so choose wisely [Range Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

You have to get the value into the function for it to read it.

As a side note I recommend using the function

```
Logger.log(url);
```

to clarify what you are doing after you run the function.

Comment: i get the url to de function by using the formula on any cell like `=url_whitout(A1)`

Comment: ok I see so what happens when you enter `=url_whitout("https:yourURLhere")` ? The issue is the A1 is undefined so you won't get a valid URL from it. I know that the cell A1 has a URL but  the function is looking for the URL to be passed into it not the cell name. That's why I suggested using the getValue() function

Comment: Not really the problem... the funtion itsef is incorrect. the url is pass correctly, i tested it using other function that are in the example here http://googleappscripting.com/working-with-urls/. Somehow it appears that uri.search is no longer valid for URI.js

Answer (score 0):

you can use protect sheet option except certain range no one will be able to edit anything except the range you choice also editors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxip5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxip5.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).